# Uber API Android oAuth - Browser Login Screen Invalid URL

Tags: android, oauth, uber-api

I am using the uberButton paradigm with callbacks. The first time I did this, the uber login screen appeared in the browser as expected, I logged in, and got the token. That token was missing the scopes = requests. Now I added the scope = requests (below).  However...

Now when I press the uber button the browser pops but the browser gives an invalid URL. So, I cannot login again and re-authenticate / get new token.

```
whiteButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);
whiteButton.setCallback(new SampleLoginCallback())
        .setSessionConfiguration(configuration);
```

I have connectivity. Here is the URL the browser goes to:
market://details?hl=en&id=com.ubercab&referrer=mat_click_id%3D85a3402dced2004e2c2430188188049d-20180108-7336%26utm_campaign%3Dpartnership%26utm_content%3DInternal%26utm_medium%3DInternal%26utm_source%3DUber%2BAPI%26utm_term%3DInternal

QUESTION: How do I get the proper Uber Login page to show up once I press the button above?

```
configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
        .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
        .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
        .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.REQUEST))
        .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
        .build();
```

Comment: One question - are you getting this kind of behavior on Emulator? Or on the phone?

Comment: @Sasa - thanks for responding. The browser response above is from the android studio emulator. On the mobile phone, Uber is installed, a white screen pops (blank/no message) that never resolves.

Answer (score 1):

If you have requested privileged scope when getting your configuration - the default behavior is to activate Single Sign On, so if there is no Uber application available on your phone - it will try to redirect you to the Play Store. The response you getting is valid in this case:

> market://details?hl=en&id=com.ubercab&...

but this is not working on emulator. You can try to run your sample on your Android phone - and you will be redirected to the Play Store to install Uber app.

Comment: thanks. Correct, There is no Uber app on the emulator. Uber is installed on the phone. Keep in mind, I successfully received an oAuth token once  on the emulator but now I can no longer. The one time it worked, I pressed the button, the browser popped with the Uber Login page, I logged on to Uber and I then got the token. Can you please tell me how I may get this working? My objective is to programmatically log on to Uber from my app and successfully request an Uber ride from my app. I am stuck and I really appreciate your help. Is my problem the callback URI or ?

Comment: If you do not have priviledged scope as "request" it will work - so you can obtain certain info from the API. If you add any priviledged scope (request, all_trips etc) you will need to have Uber app installed on the Emulator in order to make a request - othervise you will be redirected to play store to download app - and this link is not wokrig on emulator as I explained in my answer.  Check following documetation: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk

Comment: thanks - I removed the requests scope and tried it on the emulator with no Uber app installed. It resumed where I was before with the existing (no requests scope). I will try installing Uber on the emulator.  I removed the requests scope and tried it on the phone with the Uber app installed. The Uber app pops with a black screen and the Uber logo. This screen goes to white and never proceeds. How may I fix this for the phone?

Comment: I ran the app again on my phone. This time with the Uber app launched. The Uber screen pops up for a moment and then I receive "Unable to Connect - an error occurred while trying to connect, please try again later." With an "OKAY" button. I click OKAY, it reverts to my app with a toast showing "Error occurred during login INVALID_APP_SIGNATURE" The app signature (SHA1) I am using works for google maps, etc. Also, the Android code I am using came from the github location you point to above.

Comment: I validated my redirect URI is correct. I also built a signed APK and tested the key. I tested this on the phone itself. No matter what I do, with scope=requests, I either get a black/uber-then-white screen that goes nowhere or I get "INVALID_APP_SIGNATURE." Is this is a bug in the Uber SDK?